# PowerShell - paste data into Excel

Tags: excel, powershell

Today I have just thrown together this PowerShell script which

- takes a tab-delimited text file,
- reads it into memory,
- makes a variable number of filter queries based on distinct values of a certain column
- creates a new empty Excel workbook
- adds each of the subsets of filtered data to
  a new Excel worksheet

The last step is where I am stuck. Currently my code puts a few lines of data into a range in the worksheet, in the form of unrolled/transposed "key: value" entries, resulting in a horizontal data layout. The same range of data is always overwritten.

I want data in the form of a vertical layout, i.e., data in columns, just the same way as if the CSV file was imported with the import-file-wizard of MS Excel.

Is there a simpler way to do it than below?

I admit, some of the PowerShell features are pasted in here in a cargo-cult mode of programming. Please note that I have no PowerShell experience whatsoever. I did some batchfile, [VBScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript), and [VBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) coding a few years back. So, other criticisms are also welcome.

```
PARAM (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
    $infile = ".\04-2011\110404-13.txt"
)

PROCESS {
    echo " $infile"
    Write-Host "Num Args:" $args.Length;

    $xl = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application;
    $xl.Visible = $true;

    $Workbook = $xl.Workbooks.Add();

    $content = Import-Csv -delimiter "`t" $infile;
    $ports = $content | Select-Object Port# | Sort-Object Port# -Unique -Descending;
    $ports | ForEach-Object {
        $p = $_;
        Write-Host $p.{Port#};

        $Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Add();
        $workSheet.Name = [string]::Format("{0} {1}", "PortNo", $p.{Port#});
        $filtered = $content | Where-Object {$_.{Port#} -eq $p.{Port#} };
        $filtered | ForEach-Object {
            Write-Host $_.{ObsDateTime}, $_.{Port#}
        }
        $filtered | clip.exe;
        $range = $Workbook.ActiveSheet.Range("a2", "a$($filtered.count)");
        $Workbook.ActiveSheet.Paste($range, $false);
    }
    $xl.Quit()
}
```

### Data Output Example

#### Wrong

```
Port#       : 1
Obs#        : 1
Exp_Flux    : 0,99
IV Cdry     : 406.96
IV Tcham    : 16.19
IV Pressure : 100.7
IV H2O      : 9.748
IV V3       : 11.395
IV V4       : 0.759
IV RH       : 53.12
```

#### Right

```
Port#    Obs#    Exp_Flux    IV Cdry    IV Tcham    IV Pressure    IV H2O    IV V3    IV V4    IV RH
1      1    0,99    406.96    16.19    100.7    9.748    11.395    0.759    53.12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Export-Xls](http://www.lucd.info/2010/05/29/beyond-export-csv-export-xls/), it looks very nice. Never had the chance to use it, but (virtually) knowing the person who worked on it, I'm sure you will be very happy to use it. If you'll go with it, please provide a feedback here will be appreciated.

---

POSSIBLE WORKAROUND FOR UNORDERED PROPERTIES IN Export-Xls

The function `Add-Array2Clipboard` could be changed so that it accepts a new input parameter: an array providing the name of the properties ordered as required.

Then the you can change the section where `get-member` is used. Silly example:

```
"z", "a", "c" | %{ get-member -name $_ -inputobject $thecurrentobject }
```

This is just an example on how you can achieve ordered properties from `get-member`.

Comment: thanks, I'll start by taking out selected stuff from Export-Xls to improve my code. The critical parts seem to be line 138 and below.

Comment: Do you really need to create a sheet for port? Otherwise you could use `Export-Xls` directly on your `select-object` data. I mean you will be able to perform data filtering by port on excel directly.

Comment: Didn't want to do so at first, because expected powershell's confusing code-signing and security features. Still, I have used it directly as you suggested. Success! Shortened my code. Is a bit slower. Export-XLS incorrectly closes the newly created file after each iteration, creating  n entries in the "Document Recovery" dialog. Not a big deal, though.

Comment: One more slight annoyance is that Export-XLS reorders the columns, putting datetime values at the rightmost column in the excel file. Infeasible for  time series data.

Comment: Are you sure? It should follow the order of your `select-object`.

Comment: The original author of Export-XLs mentions this issue, too: http://www.lucd.info/2010/05/29/beyond-export-csv-export-xls/#comment-807. "You have no control over the order of the properties." It is a serious problem.

Comment: I would try to escape the thing modifying the `Add-Array2Clipboard` function so that it accepts an input parameter with the list of properties ordered as required. See the edit in my answer.

Comment: Now I use Export-XLS as proposed. But I had to modify the Add-Array2Clipboard function differently as you suggested. I'll post my code in a new answer, as this comment box does not allow to format code-snippets

Comment: Ok! Let me know the link. May be I'll use your solution in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the `$Workbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item($row, $col).Value2` function to more be able to pinpoint more precisely where to put the data when exporting to Excel.

Something like

```
$row = 1
Get-Content $file | Foreach-Object {
   $cols = $_.split("`t")
   for ($i = 0; $i < $cols.count; $i++)
   {
      $Workbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item($row, $i+1).Value2 = $cols[$i]
   }
   $row++
}
```

*Warning: dry-coded!* You'll probably need some `try..catch` as well.

Comment: THanks, I'll follow that hint. Apparently, from http://kentfinkle.com/PowershellAndExcel.aspx: How do I change the value of the active cell? $a.ActiveCell.Value2 = "x"; How do I change the value of a specified cell? $a.ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value2 = "y"; $ws.Cells.Item($row,1) = $_;

Answer (score 0):

I used a modified [Export-Xls](http://www.lucd.info/2010/05/29/beyond-export-csv-export-xls/) function, a bit different as User empo suggested.
This is my call to it

```
Export-Xls  $filtered -Path $outfile -WorksheetName "$wn" -SheetPosition "end"  | Out-Null #  -SheetPosition "end";
```

However, the current release of Export-Xls re-orders the columns of the in-memory representation of the csv-text -file. I want the data columns of the text file in their original order, so I had to hack and simplify the original code as follows:

```
    function Add-Array2Clipboard {
        param (
            [PSObject[]]$ConvertObject,
            [switch]$Header
        )
        process{
            $array = @();
            $line =""
            if ($Header) {

                $line = @()
                $row = $ConvertObject | Select -First 1
                $row.psobject.properties | Foreach {$line += "$($_.Name)" }
                $array += [String]::Join("`t", $line)


            }
            else {
                foreach($row in $ConvertObject){
                    $line =""
                    $vals = @()
                    $row.psobject.properties | Foreach {$vals +=  $_.Value}                      
                    $array += [String]::Join("`t", $vals)

                }

            }
            $array | clip.exe; 
        }

    }
```